# SQL server query in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-400

All,
 Have a question. I have a query which runs fine in sql server db. To run the same in DB2 what needs to be done.

```
SELECT 

     EMPID
    ,TOTALSECONDS /3600 AS Hours
    ,((TOTALSECONDS % 3600) /60) AS Minutes
    ,(TOTALSECONDS % 60) AS Seconds
    ,STATUS
    ,[DATE]
    FROM
    (SELECT
    SUM(DATEDIFF(ss,STARTDATETIME,ENDDATETIME)) AS TOTALSECONDS,
    EMPID,STATUS,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,STARTDATETIME,10) AS [DATE]
    FROM <TABLE>
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE,STARTDATETIME) = 'xxxx-xx-xx'
    GROUP BY EMPID,STATUS,CONVERT(VARCHAR,STARTDATETIME,10)) AS SUMMARY
    ORDER BY STATUS,DATE
```

Thanks.

Comment: If this is [tag:db2400]... your timestamps won't have a timezone attached.  Are they stored in UTC?  If not, does the "storage" timezone experience DST?  Heck, are you making sure all timestamps are normalized to be in the same zone (I worked on a system where we had entries apparently from the future!)?  What's the range of start vs end time - do you need to worry about changes of _when_ DST occurs (I can't remember exactly, but I don't think the system remembered multiple DST changeover dates for a zone...).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that DB2 doesn't have the `DATEDIFF` or `CONVERT` functions. There are similar ones called [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.iseries.langref2.doc%2Frbafzscatimedifstmp.htm) and [`VARCHAR_FORMAT`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzscavarcharformat.htm), respectively.

I think this query will be what you want, but I'm not 100% sure if I've converted the SQL Server formats to the DB2 formats correctly. :)

```
SELECT
     EMPID
    ,TOTALSECONDS /3600 AS Hours
    ,(MOD(TOTALSECONDS, 3600) /60) AS Minutes
    ,(MOD(TOTALSECONDS, 60) AS Seconds
    ,STATUS
    ,DATE
FROM (
    SELECT
         SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, CHAR(ENDDATETIME-STARTDATETIME))) AS TOTALSECONDS
        ,EMPID
        ,STATUS
        ,VARCHAR_FORMAT(STARTDATETIME,'mm-dd-yy') AS DATE
    FROM <TABLE>
    WHERE VARCHAR_FORMAT(STARTDATETIME,'yyyy-mm-dd') = 'xxxx-xx-xx'
    GROUP BY
         EMPID
        ,STATUS
        ,VARCHAR_FORMAT(STARTDATETIME,'mm-dd-yy')
) A
ORDER BY
     STATUS
    ,DATE
```

Comment: is the % be same. its giving error on charracter % not valid.

Comment: Oh, `%` is not the modulo operator for DB2, you want the [`MOD`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/db2/rbafzmstscale.htm#HDRSCAMOD) function. I've updated the answer.

Comment: ok.that matter solved. but now error is unexpected [DATE] was found. But date seems to be correct right

Comment: The correct escape character for DB2 is the double quote (`"`), but I don't think you'll actually need it, you can call a column `DATE` in DB2 without having to escape it. I updated the answer (again :) )

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I changed it to, DT instead of Date.. now its working fine.. changed all the HRS,MTS,SDS and DT. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please avoid `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` - from the documentation, it only returns an **estimate**, using things like 30-day months.  You don't need to explicitly cast the result of the timestamp subtraction, either.  By the time the function calcs to seconds, you're going to be _way_ off.  We need to get from the OP what version/platform of DB2 he's using, and the type of the timestamps, to see if it's safe to assume 24-hour days (historically, some legacy systems are set to timezones with DST, and some types **can't** list offset...)